# Strange chars printed on exceeding bounds of undefined length char array

Tags: c

I am pretty new to C and I have tried the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "a";
  for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
  {
    printf("%c\t%d\n", str[x],str[x]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For which I get the following output

```
a   97
    0
    0
s   115
<   60
�   -62
)   41
P   80
�   -42
�   -128
0   48
�   -41
>   62
�   -119
�   -88
U   85
    0
    0
�   -105
�   -85
```

After `str[2]` the chars are random for each execution, can someone please explain this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These random characters are just garbage from the memory. You read from a place in the memory you have not written intentionally.

Note that one should not do it. If you try to read from/write to memory you are not suppose to read from/write to, OS might kill your application.

Answer (score 0):

> After str[2] the chars are random for each execution, can someone please explain this behavior.

The behavior can't be explained; it's undefined to read or write beyond the bounds of the array. Since you have allocated two `char`s for `str` (one for the letter "a", and the other for the null terminator), reading beyond `str[2]` invokes undefined behavior, meaning that anything could happen, including breathing demons out of your nose.